# ¿Cómo pasar arraylist con todos sus datos de una clase a otra?

Tags: java, arraylist, diseño-de-clases

Tengo un `arraylist` en la clase **almacén**:

```
     ArrayList<Empleado> listaEmpleados = new ArrayList<>();
```

A ese `arraylist` le incluye empleados y en esa clase los visualizo perfectamente.

Necesito enviar el `arraylist` con todos los empleados a otra clase.

He probado creando un método:

```
public ArrayList<Empleado> getDatos() {

       return listaEmpleados;
   }
```

Y en la clase dos:

```
   Almacen alm = new Almacen();
   ArrayList<Empleado> nuevoalmacen = alm.getDatos();
```

pero sale vacío.

Comment: ¿Has rellenado con algo esa lista de empleados?

Comment: Hola @Paco, lo común es enviarlo entre Actividades, confirma si esto es lo que realizas de otra forma este proceso sería diferente. Por cierto si estas usando Android te sugiero agregues el tag en tu pregunta, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola Paco y bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español.

Empecemos por tu código:

```
Almacen alm = new Almacen();//Creas la variable alm, totalmente nueva y vacia
ArrayList<Empleado> nuevoalmacen = alm.getDatos();
```

Lo que tendrías que hacer es lo siguiente:

Cuando llames a tu `Clase2` desde tu `Clase1` tu estarás haciendo algo como esto:

```
 Clase2.metodoCualquiera();
```

De esta manera, lo que haces es llamar a la clase, por tanto cuando declaras la variable `alm` lo haces inicializandola, pero no le pasas ningún valor.

Te recomiendo hacerlo de esta manera:

```
 //Antes de pasar la variable, tendrías que inicializarla y rellenarla con los 
 //datos que quieras
 ArrayList<Empleado> listaEmpleados = new ArrayList<Empleado>();
 listaEmpleados.add(empleado1);
 listaEmpleados.add(empleado2);
 listaEmpleados.add(empleado3);
 Clase2.metodoCualquiera(listaEmpleados);
```

Y que en la `Clase2` tuvieras esto por ejemplo:

```
public static Clase2 metodoCualquiera(ArrayList<Empleado> listaEmpleados){
    Almacen alm = listaEmpleados;//esta variable contendría los datos.
    //Ahora mismo la variable alm, contendría los 3 empleados
}
```