# No puedo insertar registros en funcion postgresql con jdbc

Tags: java, postgresql, jsf, jdbc

Buen dia amigos, tengo un problema a la hora de querer insertar registros desde una llamada a una funcion de postgresql que recibe 2 parametros y lo quiero hacer desde Java Server Faces y JDBC este es mi codigo de java:

DAO:

```
 @Override
    public boolean insertPelicula(moviesDTO movies) {
        System.out.println("llllllllllllllll");
        try {

            CallableStatement prcProcedimientoAlmacenado = conn.getConnection().prepareCall("{call sp_insert_update_peliculas(?,?)}");
            prcProcedimientoAlmacenado.setInt(1, movies.getId_movie());
            prcProcedimientoAlmacenado.setString(2, movies.getMovie_name());
            prcProcedimientoAlmacenado.setInt(3, movies.getMovie_year());

            System.out.println("Executando Store Procedure...");
            prcProcedimientoAlmacenado.execute();
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Este es mi codigo del bean:

Nota: Edite la parte del bean:

```
     /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package avo.ob.movie;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;

/**
 *
 * @author phoenix
 */
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MovieBean implements Serializable {

    private List<moviesDTO> peliculasList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<moviesDTO> peliculasFitradas = new ArrayList<>();
    private String nombrePelicula = "";
    private Integer anyo;
    private MoviesDAO dao = new MovieDAOImplements();
    moviesDTO movies = new moviesDTO();

    //private MoviesDAO moviesDAO;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        peliculasList = new MovieDAOImplements().getMovies();

        //peliculasFitrados = peliculasList;
        peliculasFitradas = new ArrayList<>();
        peliculasFitradas.addAll(peliculasList);
        System.out.println("Peliculas filtradas..." + peliculasFitradas.size());

    }

    public void buscarpelicula() {
        peliculasFitradas.clear();
        for (moviesDTO item : peliculasList) {

            if (item.getMovie_name().toLowerCase().contains(nombrePelicula.toLowerCase())) {
                peliculasFitradas.add(item);
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Filtor..." + peliculasFitradas.size());

    }

    public void insertarPelicula() {

        if (movies != null) {
            System.out.println("Que onda con el insert..." + movies.getMovie_name());


            dao.insertPelicula(movies);
            //System.out.println("Que pedo con el insert..." + movies.getId_movie());


        }

    }

    public List<moviesDTO> getPeliculasList() {
        return peliculasList;
    }

    public void setPeliculasList(List<moviesDTO> peliculasList) {
        this.peliculasList = peliculasList;
    }

    public String getNombrePelicula() {
        return nombrePelicula;
    }

    public void setNombrePelicula(String nombrePelicula) {
        this.nombrePelicula = nombrePelicula;
    }

    public List<moviesDTO> getPeliculasFitradas() {
        return peliculasFitradas;
    }

    public void setPeliculasFitrados(List<moviesDTO> peliculasFitradas) {
        this.peliculasFitradas = peliculasFitradas;
    }

    public Integer getAnyo() {
        return anyo;
    }

    public void setAnyo(Integer anyo) {
        this.anyo = anyo;
    }

    public MoviesDAO getDao() {
        return dao;
    }

    public void setDao(MoviesDAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

}
```

Y por ultimo el de la vista, aqui estoy usando Java Server Faces, solo pondría el componente del botón desde se manda a llamar el insert:

```
 <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:commandButton value="Guardar Pelicula" update="data-table" actionListener="${movieBean.insertarPelicula}" process="@this"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
```

Nueva nota: Pongo también mi SP de insert del postgresql:

```
-- FUNCTION: public.sp_insert_update_peliculas(character varying, integer)

-- DROP FUNCTION public.sp_insert_update_peliculas(character varying, integer);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_insert_update_peliculas(
    out_nombrepelicula character varying,
    out_aniopelicula integer)
    RETURNS TABLE(mensaje character varying, success boolean) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$

DECLARE
var_mensaje character varying;
var_success boolean;
var_max_idmovie int;
var_n integer;
BEGIN
        var_max_idmovie := (SELECT MAX(id_movie)+1 
        FROM cat_movies);
        INSERT INTO cat_movies(
            id_movie,
            movie_name,
            movie_year)
            VALUES (var_max_idmovie,
                    $1,
                    $2);        
        GET DIAGNOSTICS var_n= ROW_COUNT;
                GET DIAGNOSTICS var_n = ROW_COUNT;
                IF(var_n>0)THEN
                    var_success=true;
                    var_mensaje='Registro agregado satisfactoriamente.';
                ELSE
                    var_success=false;
                    var_mensaje='Error en el sistema favor de contactar a su administrador.';




END IF;
    RETURN QUERY SELECT var_mensaje,var_success;
END;

--select max(id_movie) from cat_movies

$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.sp_insert_update_peliculas(character varying, integer)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Lo explico brevemente aqui basicamente está recibiendo 2 parametros que es el nombre y el año de la pelicula y el id de la pelicula se autoincrementa buscando el maximo del id_movie y se agrega a una variable y posteriormente se usa para que se inserte, no estoy seguro si tambien desde java se lo tienes que decir, y si es asi como se podria poner, por que posiblemente sea eso que este dando el null, aunque en teoria no deberia hacer eso ya que en el sp ya lo tiene.

El error que arroja es un nullpointerException al momento de dar click en el boton de "Guargar Pelicula" dejo el codigo de error:

```
29-Oct-2018 11:04:44.699 GRAVE [http-nio-8080-exec-254] com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError java.lang.NullPointerException
    at avo.ob.movie.MovieDAOImplements.insertPelicula(MovieDAOImplements.java:70)
    at avo.ob.movie.MovieBean.insertarPelicula(MovieBean.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:625)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1372)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Que onda con el insert...null
```

Desconozco que es lo que pueda estar causando el error aunque si sé lo que es: vendria siendo que quiere acceder a un objeto que está null y es por eso que manda esa exception, espero y me puedan ayudar con este problema, quedo al pendiente amigos, saludos.

Comment: El error te lo está dando en el `insertarPelicula()` porque la variable 'movies' es nula, te recomiendo ver esta respuesta, creo que es un problema similar. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/207491/cómo-pasar-arraylist-con-todos-sus-datos-de-una-clase-a-otra/207503#207503

Comment: Hola, lo extraño es que si la tengo inicializada, en el bean asi lo tengo:
moviesDTO movies = new moviesDTO();

Comment: Hola de nuevo, ya edité la parte del codigo del bean

Comment: Te llega a pintar el "Que onda con el insert..." y el name de la película?

Comment: Si, pero solo me dice que viene null y pues eso es lo extraño :/

Comment: Añadi a la pregunta todo el codigo de la funcion y una descripcion de lo que hace amigo, espero con esto se entienda mejor, saludos